# PHP script working in terminal, but not in the browser

Tags: php, xml, ncbi

In my script I'm downloading a XML file from the web and printing it's content. The problem is that it does not print the content in the browser, but it does successfully in the terminal when using

```
php index.php
```

One more thing when I use:

```
<?php $x = file_get_contents("127.0.0.1/x.xml"); var_dump($x); ?>
```

It successfully print the content of the xml in the browser but if i use:

```
<?php $x = file_get_contents($ncbi_web_address."ncbi.xml"); var_dump($x); ?>
```

It does not print the content in the browser but prints content successfully in the teminal.

**EDIT:** Not working, If code helps:

```
<?php header("Content-Type:text/plain");

search($query);

function search($query){
$url = "http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/name/".$query."/XML";
//$url = "http://127.0.0.1/x.xml"; (This one working)
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($xml);
}
?>
```

Comment: With this code I'm getting **bool(false)** .Am i doing something wrong in here.

Comment: I managed to do it via **curl**, but still wonder why file_get_contents() for websites not working.If anyone knows why.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are sending an HTML document to the browser, the XML tags will be treated as unrecognized HTML tags and ignored.

Add

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain")
```

to the top of the PHP program.